# @instance_variable."string" is not recognized inside Ruby method

Tags: ruby

I have these two methods:

```
def index
  invite_maker("invit_one")
end

def invite_maker(invit_number)
  @user = current_user
  if @user.invit_number == nil
    [...]
  end
end
```

My problem is that Ruby doesn't recognize `@user."invit_one"` as it should be `@user.invit_one`. If I put `invite_maker(invit_one)`, I get an error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@user.public_send(invit_number) == nil
```

Comment: use `public_send`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood what you want to do, but if you need to call a public method on an object with a custom string you need to use `:public_send` method.

`@user.public_send(invit_number)`
Or you can call only `:send`, this is valid for ANY method (public/protected/private).

This will call the method that has the same name as the string content.

Comment: How is this different from the answer posted by @jvillian?

Comment: Copy both answers, put these in variables and compare yourself :D Ruby will answer you

Comment: Ok. It's the same.

Comment: Congratulations!